# How do you use virual machine in Azure Devops pipeline to test new releases

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, virtual-machine

I have a requirement to test new releases using Azure Devops Pipeline once a new release is ready its need to be tested on a new virual machine. I have tried a custom image anbd storing it in the Azure Marketplace, running a create VM from Snapshot but curious to know what everyone else uses incase there is something better.

1. New release kicks off pipeline
2. pipeline creates a new FRESH virual machine and setups a startup script to add the Agent
3. then Im running it a difficult cituation how to run the test on the new vm.

anyone using similar setups?

A streamline setup where the pipeline kicks off it creates a new virtual machine from  custom image or snapshot, runs the test then reports fail or successful test .

Comment: Hi @ThomasMorgan, Have you got a chance to check my answer below to create Azure VM with pipeline agent extension via ARM template and run pipeline on the selected VM by removing tags? Hope the solution could meet your expectation and help other community members. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, the `Azure Pipelines Agent` [Azure VM extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=azure-devops#install-the-azure-pipelines-agent-azure-vm-extension) may help, since it will automatically add the new Azure VM as a target in a deployment group. And we can [Use a Resource Manager template to create an Ubuntu Linux VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-template) together with this extension.

Here is a sample pipeline workflow for your reference.

1. Create a new deployment group with the name of `DeploymentGroup-VMTest` and keep note the group id (`439` in my case);
   [image]
2. Use `ARM Template deployment` pipeline task to create a new VM; the sample ARM template below includes the installation of the `Azure Pipelines Agent` extension onto the new VM; this extension will configure the new VM as an agent target `D-Agent-r$(Release.ReleaseId)` with the tags of `Release` and `For test`; the agent will be added into the deployment group `DeploymentGroup-VMTest`;
   [image]

   **VM.json**

   ```
   {
     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
     "metadata": {
       "_generator": {
         "name": "bicep",
         "version": "0.23.1.45101",
         "templateHash": "5903517927080867595"
       }
     },
     "parameters": {
       "vmName": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "azvm-ubuntu",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "The name of your Virtual Machine."
         }
       },
       "adminUsername": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "azureuser",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
         }
       },
       "authenticationType": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "password",
         "allowedValues": [
           "sshPublicKey",
           "password"
         ],
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Type of authentication to use on the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
         }
       },
       "adminPasswordOrKey": {
         "type": "securestring",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "SSH Key or password for the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
         }
       },
       "dnsLabelPrefix": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "azvmdns",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
         }
       },
       "ubuntuOSVersion": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "Ubuntu-2004",
         "allowedValues": [
           "Ubuntu-1804",
           "Ubuntu-2004",
           "Ubuntu-2204"
         ],
         "metadata": {
           "description": "The Ubuntu version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Ubuntu version."
         }
       },
       "location": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "Southeast Asia",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Location for all resources."
         }
       },
       "vmSize": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "Standard_B1s",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "The size of the VM"
         }
       },
       "virtualNetworkName": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "vNet",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Name of the VNET"
         }
       },
       "subnetName": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "Subnet",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Name of the subnet in the virtual network"
         }
       },
       "networkSecurityGroupName": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "SecGroupNet",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Name of the Network Security Group"
         }
       },
       "securityType": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "TrustedLaunch",
         "allowedValues": [
           "Standard",
           "TrustedLaunch"
         ],
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Security Type of the Virtual Machine."
         }
       },
       "VSTSAccountName": {
         "type": "string",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "VSTS account name"
         }
       },
       "TeamProject": {
         "type": "string",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "VSTS team project name"
         }
       },
       "DeploymentGroup": {
         "type": "string",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Deployment group name"
         }
       },
       "AgentName": {
         "type": "string",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Name of the agent"
         }
       },
       "PATToken": {
         "type": "securestring",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Personal Access Token (PAT) for authentication"
         }
       },
       "Tags": {
         "type": "array",
         "metadata": {
           "description": "Tags for the VM"
         }
       }
     },
     "variables": {
       "imageReference": {
         "Ubuntu-1804": {
           "publisher": "Canonical",
           "offer": "UbuntuServer",
           "sku": "18_04-lts-gen2",
           "version": "latest"
         },
         "Ubuntu-2004": {
           "publisher": "Canonical",
           "offer": "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal",
           "sku": "20_04-lts-gen2",
           "version": "latest"
         },
         "Ubuntu-2204": {
           "publisher": "Canonical",
           "offer": "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy",
           "sku": "22_04-lts-gen2",
           "version": "latest"
         }
       },
       "publicIPAddressName": "[format('{0}PublicIP', parameters('vmName'))]",
       "networkInterfaceName": "[format('{0}NetInt', parameters('vmName'))]",
       "osDiskType": "Standard_LRS",
       "subnetAddressPrefix": "10.1.0.0/24",
       "addressPrefix": "10.1.0.0/16",
       "linuxConfiguration": {
         "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
         "ssh": {
           "publicKeys": [
             {
               "path": "[format('/home/{0}/.ssh/authorized_keys', parameters('adminUsername'))]",
               "keyData": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]"
             }
           ]
         }
       },
       "securityProfileJson": {
         "uefiSettings": {
           "secureBootEnabled": true,
           "vTpmEnabled": true
         },
         "securityType": "[parameters('securityType')]"
       },
       "extensionName": "GuestAttestation",
       "extensionPublisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Security.LinuxAttestation",
       "extensionVersion": "1.0",
       "maaTenantName": "GuestAttestation",
       "maaEndpoint": "[substring('emptystring', 0, 0)]"
     },
     "resources": [
       {
         "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
         "apiVersion": "2021-05-01",
         "name": "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]",
         "location": "[parameters('location')]",
         "properties": {
           "ipConfigurations": [
             {
               "name": "ipconfig1",
               "properties": {
                 "subnet": {
                   "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
                 },
                 "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                 "publicIPAddress": {
                   "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
                 }
               }
             }
           ],
           "networkSecurityGroup": {
             "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
           }
         },
         "dependsOn": [
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
         ]
       },
       {
         "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
         "apiVersion": "2021-05-01",
         "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
         "location": "[parameters('location')]",
         "properties": {
           "securityRules": [
             {
               "name": "SSH",
               "properties": {
                 "priority": 1000,
                 "protocol": "Tcp",
                 "access": "Allow",
                 "direction": "Inbound",
                 "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                 "sourcePortRange": "*",
                 "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                 "destinationPortRange": "22"
               }
             }
           ]
         }
       },
       {
         "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
         "apiVersion": "2021-05-01",
         "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
         "location": "[parameters('location')]",
         "properties": {
           "addressSpace": {
             "addressPrefixes": [
               "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
             ]
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
         "apiVersion": "2021-05-01",
         "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
         "properties": {
           "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetAddressPrefix')]",
           "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
           "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
         },
         "dependsOn": [
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
         ]
       },
       {
         "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
         "apiVersion": "2021-05-01",
         "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
         "location": "[parameters('location')]",
         "sku": {
           "name": "Basic"
         },
         "properties": {
           "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
           "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
           "dnsSettings": {
             "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
           },
           "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4
         }
       },
       {
         "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
         "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
         "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
         "location": "[parameters('location')]",
         "properties": {
           "hardwareProfile": {
             "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
           },
           "storageProfile": {
             "osDisk": {
               "createOption": "FromImage",
               "managedDisk": {
                 "storageAccountType": "[variables('osDiskType')]"
               }
             },
             "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')[parameters('ubuntuOSVersion')]]"
           },
           "networkProfile": {
             "networkInterfaces": [
               {
                 "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
               }
             ]
           },
           "osProfile": {
             "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
             "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
             "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]",
             "linuxConfiguration": "[if(equals(parameters('authenticationType'), 'password'), null(), variables('linuxConfiguration'))]"
           },
           "securityProfile": "[if(equals(parameters('securityType'), 'TrustedLaunch'), variables('securityProfileJson'), null())]"
         },
         "dependsOn": [
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
         ]
       },
       {
         "condition": "[and(equals(parameters('securityType'), 'TrustedLaunch'), and(equals(variables('securityProfileJson').uefiSettings.secureBootEnabled, true()), equals(variables('securityProfileJson').uefiSettings.vTpmEnabled, true())))]",
         "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
         "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
         "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('vmName'), variables('extensionName'))]",
         "location": "[parameters('location')]",
         "properties": {
           "publisher": "[variables('extensionPublisher')]",
           "type": "[variables('extensionName')]",
           "typeHandlerVersion": "[variables('extensionVersion')]",
           "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
           "enableAutomaticUpgrade": true,
           "settings": {
             "AttestationConfig": {
               "MaaSettings": {
                 "maaEndpoint": "[variables('maaEndpoint')]",
                 "maaTenantName": "[variables('maaTenantName')]"
               }
             }
           }
         },
         "dependsOn": [
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]"
         ]
       },
       {
         "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '/TeamServicesAgentLinux')]",
         "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
         "location": "[parameters('location')]",
         "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
         "dependsOn": [
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]"
         ],
         "properties": {
           "publisher": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services",
           "type": "TeamServicesAgentLinux",
           "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
           "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
           "settings": {
             "VSTSAccountName": "[parameters('VSTSAccountName')]",
             "TeamProject": "[parameters('TeamProject')]",
             "DeploymentGroup": "[parameters('DeploymentGroup')]",
             "AgentName": "[parameters('AgentName')]",
             "AgentMajorVersion": "auto|2|3",
             "Tags": "[parameters('Tags')]"
           },
           "protectedSettings": {
             "PATToken": "[parameters('PATToken')]"
           }
         }
       }
     ],
     "outputs": {
       "adminUsername": {
         "type": "string",
         "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
       },
       "hostname": {
         "type": "string",
         "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName')), '2021-05-01').dnsSettings.fqdn]"
       },
       "sshCommand": {
         "type": "string",
         "value": "[format('ssh {0}@{1}', parameters('adminUsername'), reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName')), '2021-05-01').dnsSettings.fqdn)]"
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   **Override template parameters**

   > -vmName "azvm-ubuntu-r$(Release.ReleaseId)" -adminUsername "azureuser" -authenticationType "password" -adminPasswordOrKey **$(PWD)** -dnsLabelPrefix "azvmdns-r$(Release.ReleaseId)" -ubuntuOSVersion "Ubuntu-2004" -location "Southeast Asia" -vmSize "Standard_B1s" -virtualNetworkName "vNet-r$(Release.ReleaseId)" -subnetName "Subnet-r$(Release.ReleaseId)" -networkSecurityGroupName "SecGroupNet-r$(Release.ReleaseId)" -securityType "TrustedLaunch" -VSTSAccountName **$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)** -TeamProject **$(System.TeamProject)** -DeploymentGroup **DeploymentGroup-VMTest** -AgentName **D-Agent-r$(Release.ReleaseId)** -PATToken **$(PAT)** -Tags **["For test", "Release", "r$(Release.ReleaseId)"]**
3. Use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) in a PowerShell script to remove tags for unexpected targets in the deployment group; this step is to make sure all other targets in this deployment group don't have `For test` tags expect new VM agent target `D-Agent-r$(Release.ReleaseId)`.

   ```
   Write-Host Define the URL to retrieve the list of targets in DeploymentGroup-VMTest Id: $(DeploymentGroupId)
   $targetsUrl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/$(DeploymentGroupId)/targets?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
   $targetsUrl

   # Use System.AccessToken of pipeline for API authentication
   $headers = @{
       'Authorization' = "bearer " + "$(System.AccessToken)"
       'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
   }

   Write-Host Retrieve the targets in DeploymentGroup-VMTest Id: $(DeploymentGroupId)
   $targetsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $targetsUrl  -Method Get -Headers $headers
   $targetsResponse | ConvertTo-Json

   Write-Host Loop through the targets and remove **For test** tags except D-Agent-r$(Release.ReleaseId)
   foreach ($target in $targetsResponse.value) {
       $agentName = $target.agent.name

       # Exclude the agent "D-Agent-r$(Release.ReleaseId)"
       if ($agentName -ne "D-Agent-r$(Release.ReleaseId)") {
           $targetId = $target.id
           $updateUrl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/$(DeploymentGroupId)/targets?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

           # Check if the target has the tag "For test"
           if ($target.tags -contains "For test") {
               Write-Host Remove the tag "For test" from the target $agentName
               $updateUrl
               $tags = $target.tags | Where-Object {$_ -ne "For test"}

               Write-Host Romove all tags for $agentName
               $body = @"
   [
       { 
           "id": "$targetId",
           "tags": []
       }
   ]
   "@

               $body
               $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateUrl -Method PATCH -Headers $headers -Body $body
               $result.value | ConvertTo-Json
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Run tests in a deployment group job, which will requires the target with tag `For test` and only the new VM agent `D-Agent-r$(Release.ReleaseId)` has the tag `For test`;
   [image]